# Exam Package - Grade Table - Summation of the points

Tags: exam

Is there a way to skip one of the questions (for example question 9) in the summation of the points in the grade table of the exam package? I want that the 4 points for question 9 is not in the total points, so the total points should be 60[image]

Comment: Do you still want question 9 in the table? If yes, should it have 4 points or 0 points in the table?

Comment: Also it would help if you can provide a minimal document that generates this output, with the documentclass and the required packages (`exam` and `babel` are probably sufficient) and a few dummy questions, so that when it is compiled without adding any extra code it results in the output that you show here. This would make it much faster for somebody that is interested in asnwering the question to get started without doing all the extra work of setting up a document.

Comment: It should have 4 Point in the Table but it should not be included in the sum of the points (like a bonus question - but without an Bonustable)

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't that be confusing, if the numbers in the table don't add up to the total?

Comment: maybe you could have a look at bonus points from the `exam` class documentation